# send email from the email entered by the user

Tags: reactjs, react-native, email

If a user sends an email from my application it should show the user's email Id in the "from" field of the email. I am working in react native. please name any technology or service which can do so and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the app needs to open up the client email app on the user device (android & ios).

At the core, React native provides a Linking library for deep linking with external apps.

```
  const sendMail = async () => {

    try {

       const recipient = "bill@microsoft.com"
       const title = "Acquire Unicorn metaverse start-up";
       const body = "Don't lie behind Zuck back. Metaverse is the future..."

      const url = `mailto:${recipient}?cc=&subject=${title}&body=${body}`;
      await Linking.openURL(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

The function will open the email client app and pass  `email`, `title`, and `body` parameters to the email client.

Explore more at https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: Sir I cant thank you enough. I am new to android development so I didn't know much about linking this helped a lot

Comment: Approve also this answer as correct. This will help future developers